ABAP CDS View - ON and Where Clause Using Substring
I create SAP ABAP CDS view using Z table join with table AUFK and COBRB. I want filter field GABJA based on year of KEYDT and field GABPE based on month of KEYDT. But, when I put code c.gabja = substring(a.keydt, 1, 4) and c.gabpe = substring(a.keydt, 5, 2) the result is empty even though the data is there.
Is it possible that the cause of this error is due to a difference in data types?
I also include my CDS view below.
define view ZCDS_COBRB 
as select from zcktfi_zar01 as a
inner join aufk as b on a.caufn = b.aufnr
inner join cobrb as c on b.objnr = c.objnr and c.objnr like 'OR%' 
{
   key a.bukrs       as bukrs,
   key a.afabe1      as afabe1,
   key a.keydt       as keydt,
   c.ps_psp_pnr      as posnr,
   a.pspid           as pspid,
   a.kostl           as kostl,
   a.stort           as stort,
   c.objnr           as caufn
} where a.bukrs = '3000' and c.gabja = substring(a.keydt, 1, 4) and c.gabpe = substring(a.keydt, 5, 2)

The cause of the error and the way to solve the problem

cobrb.gabpe is NUMC 3, not 2. Pad left with '0'.
